# Program to calculate the area underneath a graph

Tags: python, list, function

I'm writing a program that will calculate the area under a graph by counting trapeziums. It has the following steps:

1. Ask the user for a graph function, boundary points (on the x-axis), and number of trapeziums they want to count
2. Find the width of each trapezium, by dividing the length between the boundary points by the number of trapeziums.
3. Find the height of the graph (its y-value) at each trapezium's start and end point.
4. Apply the formula for the area of a trapezium, to find the area of each trapezium. Then sum these values to find the total area under the graph.

```
import numpy 

# Our function, along with boundary values and total number of trapeziums (N)
def f(x):
    return x*2
x1 = float(input('Define first boundary value'))
x2 = float(input('Define second boundary value'))
N = float(input('Define number of trapeziums used'))

# The width of each trapezium, w
w = abs(float((x2-x1)/N))

# The true heights, or y value, of each trapezium's end points
heights = []
for h in numpy.arange(x1, x2+w, w):
    heights.append(h)
realheights = [f(h) for h in heights]

# Applying the defined function (1/2((h1+h2)*w)), to find the area of each trapezium
```

I've used `x*2` as a placeholder function, but would want the user to be able to define what function they want. I also don't know how to apply the function, to find the area of a trapezium, to the values of realheights.

Comment: Note that if you order your x1 and x2 so that x1 is always less than x2 (`if x2 < x1: x1,x2 = x2,x1`) you don't need the `abs` call, and if you import numpy, you then also don't need that intermediate heights code because you can just say `heights = [f(x) for x in np.linspace(x1, x2, N+1)]` directly (with N+1 because you don't want N values, you want N _intervals_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy



# Function to calculate the area under the curve
def calculate_area(f, x1, x2, N):
    # The width of each trapezium, w
    w = abs((x2 - x1) / N)

# The true heights, or y value, of each trapezium's end points
heights = numpy.linspace(x1, x2, N+1)
realheights = [f(h) for h in heights]

# Applying the formula for the area of each trapezium
area = 0
for i in range(N):
    area += 0.5 * (realheights[i] + realheights[i+1]) * w

return area

# Get user inputs

x1 = float(input('Define first boundary value: '))
x2 = float(input('Define second boundary value: '))
N = int(input('Define number of trapeziums used: '))

# Prompt the user to input the function as a string and evaluate it
function_str = input('Define the function (e.g., "x**2" for x squared): ')
f = lambda x: eval(function_str)

# Calculate and print the area under the curve
area = calculate_area(f, x1, x2, N)
print('Area under the curve:', area)
```

Output:
[image]